# Android Loosing referrer when opened in the Play Store from the browser

Tags: android, install-referrer

I am trying to retrieve referral content with the [Play Install Referrer Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library)
but it doesn't work when the play store is opened via the browser (the referrer is lost).